# Python : I'm unable to fix TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, pandas

I've this code in python :

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import os
import pandas as pd

Server = os.listdir('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers/')
ServerList = widgets.Dropdown(options = (Server))

Date = ['2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01']
DateList = widgets.Dropdown(options = (Date))

display(ServerList,DateList)

Test = os.listdir('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers'+ '/'+ ServerList.value + '/'+ DateList.value+'/')

Path = ('/home/tim/Bureau/Servers'+ '/'+ ServerList.value + '/'+ DateList.value+'/' + str(Test).strip("[]").strip("''") )
display(Path)

df = pd.read_csv(Path)
display(df)
```

The result is :

[image]

But I've this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-2664737bd451> in <module>
     17 display(Path)
     18 
---> 19 df = pd.read_csv(Path)
     20 display(df)
     21 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I know I used a `str` with `str(Test)` but it's the only solution that I find to do what I want and I don't know how to fix this error.

I would like to recover the path to put in in a `pd.read_csv` in order to display the csv.
Can you show me please ?

Comment: It's better to use `os.path.join()` to create pathnames instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Does `print(type(pd.read_csv))` return `str` ?

Comment: Is this really the whole script? You've done something that has replaced the `pd.read_csv` function with a string.

Comment: Hello all !
Indeed, I've an other `str`. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to convert df to a pandas dataframe with:

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: There is no data variable in his script. Also, there is no need for this as the pd.read_csv()-method already returns a dataframe :)